# Simplest way to have a marker without a pin in mapbox

Tags: javascript, marker, mapbox

What's the simplest way to have a marker without a pin in mapbox.js, for example a circle marker like the TileMill default one? I have lots of points and the pin is way too heavy.

```
var marker = L.marker(marker_latlng, {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#f22',
        'marker-symbol': 'circle-stroked'
    }),
    title: "Taxi",
    draggable: false
}).addTo(map);
```

Don't want | Want

[image]
[image]

Basically I would like the circle marker only, without the pin around it.

Possible solutions I thought about:

- draw a circle per every point
- use a custom pin image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scaled-markers/)? I think it does what you want... when you set the marker symbol to circle its putting a circle icon inside the marker.. you want the whole marker to be a circle so you need to change the marker to `circleMarker`

Comment: This seems to do what I was after. I'm pretty sure it wasn't there when I was searching for it. Thanks!

Comment: @gozzilli sure thing :) I just started using it and was trying to do the same thing! so in your case it would be `L.circleMarker` instead of `L.marker` if im not mistaken